# how to import data from mysql into hive by sqoop1.99.3

Tags: sqoop

I have just installed sqoop 1.99.3  and imported a table into HDFS from mysql.Now I want import a table into hive or hbase from mysql by sqoop,but I don't know how to do this.The command 'sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ip:port/dbName --username root --password mysql-password --table' for sqoop 1.4.* doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For habse :
 `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ip:port/dbName --username UserName --password MysqlPassword --table TableName --hbase-table HbaseTableName --column-family ColumnFamilyName`
for hive :
`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://ip:port/dbName --username UserName --password MysqlPassword --table HiveTableName --hive-import`,
Substitute table name and column family name as per your requirement.

Comment: THX for your help.But sqoop1.99.3 cant't run as command ./sqoop + parameters. My colleague just told me that sqoop1.99.3 doesn't support hive.So maybe I'll choose sqoop1.4.4 instead.

Comment: thank you Shiqi.. I had used sqoop a long time ago, and looks like they changed sqoop2 a lot comapred to sqoop1. I am also currently looking into that..